# Comparing two date fields and writing an Utility Class - Apex, Salesforce

Tags: apex, salesforce1-app, java

I have two date fields

1. Manager_recruitment_date__c
2. Recruitment_officer_date__c

I would want to write a utility class where I want to compare both these fields, and take the Max date and use it somewhere else in my logic.

```
Date Mydate;

If (o.Manager_recruitment_date__c != null || o.recruitment_officer_date__c != null) {

    if (o.Manager_recruitment_date__c > o.recruitment_officer_date__c) {
         Mydate = o.Manager_recruitment_date__c;
    } else {
        Mydate = o.recruitment_officer_date__c;
    }

}
```

I am I doing it right? Does this qualify for all combinations of any of the date field being null?

Thanks

Answer (score 0):

No, that would not work with first if-statement, BOTH dates need to be NOT null:

```
Manager_recruitment_date__c != null && recruitment_officer_date__c != null
```

The second error is that you're not assigning max value to your variable, needs to be:

```
Mydate = Manager_recruitment_date__c;
```

and

```
Mydate = recruitment_officer_date__c;
```

The third error is that you're using fields without actual sObject, so I severely doubt that your class will compile.

Comment: My bad, o.Manager_recruitment_date__c  is the sobject reference I am using,. What is the 2nd comment you have made? I am assigning inside the loop is it not right?

Comment: But there is no loop in your example. And you want to have max value assigned to Mydate and not to the fields.

Answer (score 0):

If you just want to use the Maximum of **Manager_recruitment_date__c** and
**Recruitment_officer_date__c** in your code , then you can create a formula field on the same object which will give you the Maximum of these two days and query that field to use in your logic.

IF( (Date1 -  Date2) > 0 , Date1, 
     IF((Date1 -  Date2) < 0, Date2, 
        IF(ISBLANK( Date1 ) && NOT( ISBLANK( Date2 ) ), Date2  , 
           IF(ISBLANK( Date2 ) && NOT( ISBLANK( Date1 ) ), Date1 , null) ) ) )